# Definir un formato para un atributo datetime en un modelo usando .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp, model-view-controller

tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BAT.Models
{
    public class Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi idea es definir un formato para que en la vista se muestre automáticamente el formato que defina en el modelo. Actualmente en la vista se me muestran las fechas con el formato `mes/día/año horas/minutos/segundos`, pero yo quiero el formato `horas/minutos/segundos día/mes/año`. Ya sé que podría usar la función `ToString()` y darle el parámetro adecuado, pero eso me implica aplicar la función para cada parte donde se muestra la fecha.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 especialmente el punto #3.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que muestras el modelo de base de datos, en ese caso no deberías cambiar la forma de escribir o leer el campo dado sigue siendo un `dateTime` independientemente de cómo lo quieras mostrar.

Puedes hacerlo añadiendo una propiedad que formatee ese campo como quieras, por ejemplo:

```
public string FechaCreacionFormateada
{ 
     get { return $"{FechaCreacion:HH/MM/ss}"; }
}
```